# In Thunderbird, how to save an attached email directly to a mail folder?

Tags: email, thunderbird, attachments

In Outlook, if I receive an email that has another email as an attachment (e.g. sender did "Forward as attachment" on an email, or an email attached to a bounce message), I can save a copy of the attached email directly to a mail folder by dragging it from the list of attachments in the open email, and dropping it into one of my mail folders.

I have been unable to find the same functionality in Thunderbird. I can save the attached email to a folder in the filesystem as an .eml file, but I want to save it directly to a mail folder instead.

How can I do that?

By the way, currently using TB on a Mac, to connect using IMAP

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: How is your Thunderbird configured? Pop or IMAP?

Comment: It's configured for IMAP